# How to re-render a component if a variable changes in React (with Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

(Edit: I found something else wrong with the code and fixed it. So this question becomes irrelevant.)

How to re-render the `MyComponent` component when `const language` changes? Now it works only when I switch the tabs, but I need it working when the language is changed in another component.

```
import React from "react";
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";

export default function MyComponent(props: any) {
    const language: string = useSelector((state: any) => state.config.language);
......
}
```

Comment: It should already be the case, if you are using redux properly.

Comment: Most likely you're not changing the state of language correctly through your actions or something is not quite setup on the reducer

Answer (score 1):

Like said, if you are using redux properly it should alrealdy be re-rendering...

But if it dont, in a last case, you can force a re-render in the component by setting a key in parent div and changing its values whenever it config languague changes.

By request an example:

```js
const [rerenderedComponent, setRerenderedComponent] = useState(1);

const forceUpdate = () => {
 return setRerenderedComponent(prev => prev + 1);
}

return (
<div onClick={forceUpdate} key={rerenderedComponent}>
...
</div>
)
```

Comment: Can you please give some exapmle?

Comment: I just edited my answer with an example...